# Увидел этот код, но не знаю, как он работает

Tags: swift, swift3, if

```
func sortFunc (array: [Int], closure: (Int?, Int) -> Bool) -> Int {
   var tempVar: Int? = nil
   for value in array {
      if closure (tempVar, value) {
         tempVar = value
      }
   }
   return tempVar!
}
```

Из этого кода непонятен этот элемент

```
if closure (tempVar, value) {
   tempVar = value
}
```

Как он работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код перебирает массив целых чисел, переданный как первый параметр, и проверяет каждое значение с помощью функции, переданной как второй параметр.

Как я понимаю, это универсальная фунция сортировки. Второй параметр (функция) и определяет правило сортировки. Т.е. может быть по возрастанию, по убыванию...

Answer (score 0):

Это вызов функциональной переменной внутри функции. 
Оператор сравнения вызывает функцию, которую передали в качестве параметра.
Более подробно можно почитать здесь:
["Swiftbook"](http://swiftbook.ru/doc/functions/function-types)

Answer (score -1):

if closure (tempVar, value) {

```
  tempVar = value
```

}
Клоужер(замыкание), которое принимает опциональную переменную tempVar и элемент массива value.  Если выражение closure (tempVar, value) = true, то value записывается в tempVar.
Например, поиск наибольшего элемента массива

var s = [1,5,7,3,8,5,9,2,4,7]

*let m = sortFunc(array: s, closure: { (a,b) in

```
if a != nil {
    return a! < b
}
return true
```

})*
m будет равно 9
(немного короче запись замыкания)

let m = sortFunc(array: s, closure: {

```
if $0 != nil {
    return $0! < $1
}
return true
```

})

Comment: От себя добавте пояснений, что-бы это было похоже на ответ.